# AWK: splitting URL into parts and print

Tags: awk, url

I have these two

```
http://www.example.com:8888/index.php
```

`http://home.example.com:8888/index.php` (`home` can be anything but `www`)

and want to get this:

```
example.com

home.example.com
```

Preferably in some readable way so I understand how it works in a year from now.

This is my attempt:

```
echo http://www.example.com:8888/index.php | awk -F[/:\'www\'] '{print $7}'
```

but the result is

`.example.com` (note the dot) when applied to www.example.com

it works fine for `home.example.com` if I `print $4` but I would prefer if I could use the same print-clause in both cases.

Thank you.

Comment: `awk -F'[/:]' '{gsub(/www./,""); print $4}'`

Answer (score 1):

**`sed`** solution:

```
sed -E 's~http://(www\.)?([^:]+).*~\2~' file
```

- `~` - treated as `sed` subcommand separator
- `-E` - allows extended regexps
- `(www\.)?` - matches optional `www.` part
- `([^:]+)` - matches any character sequence except `:`

---

The output:

```
example.com
home.example.com
```

Answer (score 1):

In three steps:

1. Remove everything up to the `://` in the URL.
2. Remove everything after the first `/` or `:` in the remaining string.  This now leaves you with only the hostname from the original URL.
3. Remove bits that you don't want, e.g. `www.` from the start of the hostname.

```
sed -e 's@^.*://@@' -e 's/[/:].*$//' -e 's/^www\.//'
```

Running this on your example URLs will yield

```
example.com
home.example.com
```

---

Using `awk`:

```
awk -F'[/:]+' '{ sub("^www\.", "", $2); print $2 }'
```

This treats the input lines as records of fields delimited by any number of consecutive `:` or `/`. This means that the hostname will be available in the second field on each line.

The `sub()` will simply remove the bit of the hostname that we are not interested in (here, `www.` at the start of the hostname).

Answer (score 0):

Using GNU awk and its field pattern definition `FPAT`:

```
 awk -v FPAT='([^/]+\\.)+[^:/]+' '{print $1}'
```

The field pattern is set to a sequence of character excluding the `/` followed by a dot `.` and must terminate with either `:` or `/`.

Maybe a little too permissive for an URL but it catches fqdn with and without port number.